# Floating div at center doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, css, html, alignment

let's say i have fallowing html-

```
    <div  id="submitPage" align="center" >
<div id="middlecontainer">
<p align="center" id="loading-image">&nbsp;<img  src="/cso/images/loading.gif" border="0" > <font color="red" >Submiting order...</font></p>
</div>
</div>
```

i am trying to float  submitPage div at center of page...i ahve used fallowing css and it's working fine in Mozila but don't know why it's not working in IE-8..

```
#submitPage {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 746px;
 height:201px;
 background: aqua; 
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 99;
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
 margin:90px auto;
}
#middlecontainer{
 text-align: center;
 width: 91px;
margin: 0 327px;
}
#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 74px;
  left: 299px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Please let me now if i am doing something wrong or missing something which needs to be added for IE.Any way to doing it by using Jquery will also be appreciated.

[**Mozila Screen Shot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD7tz.png)

Thanks.!

Comment: the text only i.e. is Submitting order... , in my case

Comment: maybe you should have a jsfiddle.net for this

Comment: in jsfidle it's working fine in both mozila and ie..but don't know why not working in my code.you can see it here..http://jsfiddle.net/CJgMz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me for saying so, but... what a mess. Mixing HTML attributes and CSS, centering, centering and centering. And centering. And font tags. And centering...

You should avoid to specify centered text for an element that contains block elements, because IE handles that incorrectly and applies the centering on block elements, not only the text.

As you are just placing some text and an image in an element, you only need the element, the image, and the text:

```
<div  id="submitPage">
  <img src="/cso/images/loading.gif" alt="">Submitting order...
</div>

#submitPage {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 746px;
  height: 201px;
  background: #0ff; 
  z-index: 99;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 90px;
  margin-left: -373px;
  line-height: 201px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f00;
}
#submitPage img{
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pkMqM/

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** please optimize your CSS too, `color:red` has been deprecated ;

see the DEMO below

### http://jsfiddle.net/2GmC4/

Comment: @diEcho What has been deprecated about `color: red`? Using names instead of hex values or `rgba()`?

Comment: @alex yes, use hex value  see the article  : http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.1

Comment: @diEcho- i don't know why, but when i used your approach , it visible in IE too..would you please tell me what was wrong in my css accept "color:red" :)

Comment: @diEcho The first article you linked says the `bgcolor` attribute has been deprecated. The second one was on the money though. :)

Comment: @Vivek there are many repetitive property like `align: center`and many more.Please examine yourself. thanks...if this is useful answer then upvote and accept..Thanks :)

Comment: @alex :) thats why i sent you another link :)